# Migrar codigo VBA a python

Tags: python, vba

soy nuevo en python y quise migrar este codigo VBA a python y la estoy pasando mal, algún héroe sin capa que me ayude a migrarlo?
aqui el codigo:

```
Sub m1()

Dim CantAlumnos,Nota1,Nota2,Nota3,Nota4 As Integer

Dim NomAlum, Literal As String

Dim promedio As Double

CantAlumnos = InputBox("ingrese cant de alumnos")

For i = 1 To CantAlumnos

    NomAlum = InputBox("ingrese nombre alumno ")
    
        Nota1 = Int(InputBox("ingrese nota1: "))
        Nota2 = Int(InputBox("ingrese nota2: "))
        Nota3 = Int(InputBox("ingrese nota3: "))
        Nota4 = Int(InputBox("ingrese nota4: "))
        
        promedio = (Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 + Nota4) / 4
           
        If promedio > 90 Then
            Literal = "A"
        ElseIf promedio > 80 Then
            Literal = "B"
        ElseIf promedio > 70 Then
            Literal = "C"
        ElseIf promedio > 60 Then
            Literal = "D"
        ElseIf promedio <= 60 Then
            Literal = "F"
        End If
    MsgBox NomAlum & " : " & promedio & " - " & Literal  
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: que se supone que hace el código de vba? Recuerda que hay personas que pueden saber python pero no vba

Comment: esta super sencillo de leer Christian, el algoritmo pide que se ingrese la cantidad de alumnos y hace un recorrido por la cantidad de alumnos, en cada iteracion guarda 4 notas, las promedia y las imprime. Mi duda es como pasarlo a python

Comment: solo los imprime? no los guarda en archivo ni nada?

Comment: si, solo imprime en pantalla

Comment: Y la parte de python que llevas hecha? ¿Qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: es que soy nuevo en python y no se como se declara un array, for, if; soy nuevo nuevo nuevo en este lenguaje

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pues no es muy difícil, casi todo tiene una equivalencia muy exacta. Lo único es que en Python no se declaran las variables ni se especifica el tipo de dato, solo se inicializan con un valor.

```py
num_alumnos = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos: "))

for _ in range(num_alumnos):
    name = input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
    nota1 = int(input("Ingrese la nota1: "))
    nota2 = int(input("Ingrese la nota2: "))
    nota3 = int(input("Ingrese la nota3: "))
    nota4 = int(input("Ingrese la nota4: "))
    
    prom = sum([nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4])/4
    nota = None
    
    if prom > 90:
        nota = "A"
    elif prom > 80:
        nota = "B"
    elif prom > 70:
        nota = "C"
    elif prom > 60:
        nota = "D"
    elif prom <= 60:
        nota = "F"

    print(f"{name}:{prom}-{nota}")
```

Utilizamos un `_` en el `for` ya que no necesitamos *manejar* una variable de *control* (por ejemplo `i`). Con la función `sum()` sumamos los elementos de una lista, esto solo para evitar hacer `nota1 + nota2 +...`, esto tendría más sentido/utilidad si en vez de pedir cada valor por separado pedimos todos a la vez y luego los separamos. Todas las líneas donde se piden las notas se pueden reducir a:

```py
#...
for _ in range(num_alumnos):
    name = input("Ingrese el nombre: ")
    notas = input("Ingrese las notas separadas por espacios")
    notas = [int(n) for n in notas.split()]
    prom = sum(notas)/len(notas)
    #... resto del código
```

Para ello utilizamos una comprensión de lista (que es igual que un ciclo `for` pero reducido) donde recorremos la entrada (convertida a lista por `split()`) donde cada número es un elemento y convertimos ese elemento a un entero con `int()`. Con esto ya podemos ingresar una *infinidad* de notas, ya que al sacar el promedio se dividirá entre la cantidad de notas ingresadas y no entre un número fijo.

Para imprimir utilizamos los *f-strings* los cuales nos facilitan poner variables en el texto a imprimir utilizando las llaves `{}`, dentro de estas irán las variables.

Comment: lo maximo Christian, eres un crack